# Why does my jquery reset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to make a second dropdown navigation here, all i want it to do is slide down nicely once its been triggered to show and it does slide down. However it disappears just after a second or so, why does it do that??

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Toggle</a>
  </nav>
  <div id="lower_nav">
    This is some text.
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

SASS

```
*
  margin: 0

header
  background-color: tomato
  height: 120px

nav
  background-color: brown
  padding: 20px
  a
    color: white

div
  background-color: f0f0f0

#lower_nav
  background-color: blue
  padding: 20px
  color: white
  display: none
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
  $("a").on("click", function() {
    $("#lower_nav").slideDown();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that by clicking a link i am reloading a page, therefore my bar is disappearing. I solved this with jquery's preventDefault function.